# Amazon SNS Push Notification - Autoregister device token to aws console

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-sdk

i am using Amazon SNS Push notification using GCM service.

I am able to manually add device token in aws console and receive notifications on the device.

No how can i auto register device token to aws console ?

According to the docs [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-send-devicetoken.html) we need to use Cognitio but there is no proper documentation for the same.

Can you guys help me solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read this [article](https://medium.com/aws-activate-startup-blog/a-guide-to-amazon-simple-notification-service-mobile-push-self-registration-for-ios-a2502e8d5fbd) to know the whole workflow. Though it's written for iOS development and somewhat outdated, the concepts are helpful.

AWS Cognito helps you get credentials for connecting your application users with AWS SNS Service. It's important to first set up Cognito to authorize any further action.

For the auto registration part,
you'll need to make a request to AWS console and create an `endpoint` (related to a specific device installed your application) there, 
thus you can push notifications to those registered endpoints later.

check the **createPlatformEndpoint** (keyword for more searching) section at this [AWS doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html).

Notice that two request parameters `PlatformApplicationArn` and `Token` are required, see the **Request Parameters** section [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/APIReference/API_CreatePlatformEndpoint.html).

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I manually get the devices token for testing on aws coonsole?